# Mouse indicator moves differently in Ubuntu 22.04, than in ealier distributions

Tags: mouse-pointer

My mouse indicator move differently in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, than in earlier distributions, how to set the same configuration as in earlier distributions. I do not aim at objects at the first time :( I have an ASUS WT465M mouse. Help, please! I have just adjusted the mouse speed configuration on max, but it does not work :(

I would like to set a configuration as in earlier distributions.

Comment: Can you explain what’s different about how the mouse moves?

Comment: I think that the acceleration is too small. But does someone know the previous configuration?